# MATLAB: Finding files within a directory with specific names?

Tags: regex, matlab, file, file-processing

If I have files with multiple names and I want to select only few from them, how can I do that in MATLAB.
For e.g. I have the following file names in a directory

1adl.txt, 2adl.txt...

1adlKey.txt, 2adlKey.txt ...

where *adl.txt are the files containing data and *Key.txt are the files containing 'keys' to extract useful information from a*.txt

The problem is when I use

```
files = dir(fullfile(newdir,'*.txt') );
```

it gives me all the .txt files, whereas I want to read a*.txt and a*Key.txt separately, so I can do a one-to-one correspondence between them.
Can regular expression be used here? If so, then how?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Comment: keyfiles came out fine, but for nokeyfiles i had to do some manipulation, however your answer was partially correct.

Comment: Interesting, I found no problems when I tested. Would you mind sharing your workaround? Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 2):

I'd do the following to read them separately:

```
nokeyfiles = dir(fullfile(newdir,'?a?[^Key].txt'));
keyfiles = dir(fullfile(newdir,'*Key.txt'));
```

Answer (score 0):

See the following code line.

```
files = dir(fullfile(newdir,'*adl*.txt') );
```

Pls visit Matlab Documentation for more information on `dir` command.